# Resize fancybox to vimeo video size

Tags: jquery, fancybox, vimeo

I have a few video thumbnails on a webpage. When I click one, I want a fancybox to open and play the Vimeo video with no black bars, so the aspect ratio has to be right. Unfortunately, fancybox can't detect the right width&height of the video.

I wrote some jquery code but I'm stuck in the last step:

```
var $height = screen.height/2;
var $aspectRatio = 16/9; // Default aspect ratio
var $width = $aspectRatio * $height; // Default width

$('a.fancybox-media').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    width : $width,
    height : $height,
    autoDimensions : false,
    beforeLoad : function() {
        var $vimeoVideoID = jsTheme.fancybox.getVimeoId(this.href);

        $.getJSON('http://www.vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + $vimeoVideoID + '.json?callback=?', {format: "json"}, function(data) {
            // Calculate aspect ratio & new width
            $aspectRatio = data[0].width / data[0].height;
            $width = $aspectRatio * $height;
        }).done(function() {
            // Resize fancybox to this width & height. Doesn't work!
            this.width = $width; 
            this.height = $height;
        });
    }
});
```

I can do the API call and retrieve the width and height from the Vimeo API. I calculate the new width based on this aspect ratio. But I can't set the width. Even if I hardcode the width in the `done` function like `this.width = '3000'` **it doesn't update fancybox**.

If I put `this.width = '3000'` outside of the done function, it works. Seems like I can't update fancybox from the done function. Can I force this update? Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: `this` inside `done` callback isn't referring to fancybox instance. The easiest way is then to use a referenced variable: `beforeLoad : function() { var self = this;` then use `self` inside done callback

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :** *(Get data first, then open Fancybox)*

```
var id = 132693003;
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://www.vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + id + '.json?callback=?',
    success: function (json) {
        var w = json[0]['width'];
        var h = json[0]['height'];
        $.fancybox.open({
            width: w,
            height: h,
            maxWidth: 1240,
            padding: 0,
            type: 'iframe',
            aspectRatio: true,
            scrolling : 'no',
            href: '//player.vimeo.com/video/' + id + '?color=d50000&autoplay=1&hd=1&show_title=0&show_byline=0&show_portrait=0&fullscreen=1'
        });
    }
});
```

***PS*** : Without Fancybox media helper